# How to perform Push Notification in adobe Phonegap using Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, hybrid-mobile-app

Currently I am developing hybrid application using Adobe phonegap. I have created java web based application which contains .html, javascript and css files. I have put server side code into cloud.

I have developed hybrid app. but now i have to implement Push Notification in the same application. so i have visited different links for it, but i am confused between either i have to perform it with Android based IDE or Platform or i can directly perform it using Google cloud Messaging or Firebase cloud Messaging.

Is it compulsory to use Android or iOS based Studio or platform?
Is there any plugins related to push notification?

Give me some suggestions regarding implementing Push notification in hybrid Applcation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FCM and GCM is not available longer.

So FCM is avialable for both android and ios.
For integration you can checkout this repository:

```
https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm
```

Its very simple and easy integration.

Comment: I have read https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm this link.